# Why there is a comma

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have read a passage recently, but there is something that makes me confused. Why there is a comma after "eliminate", before "many", and I reckon that this sentence may be correct without the comma. Hope you guys can help me with it. Thanks a lot!

Here is the passage.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma after eliminate is paired with the one after ignore to delimit a *[parenthetical clause](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-parenthetic-clause-230141)*. In this sentence the phrase "and thus eventually to eliminate" adds extra information but isn't essential to the meaning of the sentence as a whole.

This phrase can be eliminated without the sentence losing meaning, e.g.

> It tends to ignore many elements in the land community that lack commercial value, but that are essential to its healthy functioning.

Comment: I get it! Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a very good example of a parenthetical where zero punctuation bracketing is a very valid choice.